# How to Configure Folder Access in "Document & Media Portlet" by Organization in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, document, folder-permissions

I would like to add a section to allow customers to upload / download files (create directories) in portal website. Files / Directories should be stored on the File Server, whereas we should be able to set the ROOT folder in LifeRay.
Example; `<Root Folder> \ <Customer Name> \ <Customer’s files and directories>` . where Customer as an organization. Liferay version is 6.2.

Folder Directories/documents created by user of one customer should not be accessible by user of some other customer.

We have a following structure:

1. Customer A = Organization A

   - User A1 (Organization Admin)
   - User A2 (User)
   - Directory name to upload document = "Customer A"
2. Customer B = Organization B

   - User B1 (Organization Admin)
   - User B2 (View,Write Access in Document media)
   - User B3 (View Access)
   - Directory name to upload document = "Customer B"

When any user from "Customer A" upload any document, document visible scope should be within the "Organization A" only, same for the Organization B.

All the users will use single website to share the content.
I have a tried to create a Site team by organization and then set access for respective folder but it doesn't work. Also, I tried to create a different organization role and assign to respective organization users.

Can I achieve this with configuration, or I need to do custom development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating a regular role and then assigning it to the organization? I don't know if it will automatically set the permission properly, but if I understand Liferay correctly, the user who created the file and should be able to set the permissions to it. If they made it so only users with the regular role that's assigned to their organization will be able to see it.

The problem with setting an organization role (at least from my understanding of 
Liferay, someone please correct me if I've misunderstood Liferay permissions) is that the permission is only applied to one specific organization, and doesn't apply to the other organizations, so they will still be able to see it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i did it  using creating organization site, so directory specific to that site can be accessed by users of organization or member of the site.